# python installing thread-local storage

Tags: python, cryptography, installation

I'm trying to install a pysnap library from github. This is part of the output I get. I have no idea how to proceed, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Installed /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysnap-0.1.1-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for pysnap==0.1.1
Searching for cryptography>=1.2.2
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/cryptography/
Best match: cryptography 1.2.3
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/c/cryptography/cryptography-1.2.3.tar.gz#md5=5474d2b3e8c7555a60852e48d2743f85
Processing cryptography-1.2.3.tar.gz
Writing /tmp/easy_install-7ZnmT5/cryptography-1.2.3/setup.cfg
Running cryptography-1.2.3/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-7ZnmT5/cryptography-1.2.3/egg-dist-tmp-rcoXcx
_configtest.c:1:1: error: thread-local storage is unsupported for the current target
__thread int some_threadlocal_variable_42;

1 error generated.
error: unable to create target: 'No available targets are compatible with this triple, see -version for the
  available targets.'
1 error generated.
```

Answer (score 0):

What platform are you trying to install pysnap?
 I downloaded and installed pysnap sucessfully from  [this github location](https://github.com/martinp/pysnap)

I do have windows 10 platform and python 2.7 though. I dont' have a linux to replicate this issue.

If you are trying to install on  Linux, depending on flavor and its setup , sometimes swap is setup as as /tmp and some applications are not able to write to /tmp. In your case it does looks like its trying to write to /tmp and erroring out.

Can you try `pip install cryptography`
 and see if its able to install `cryptography` part without issues?

Once that dependency is out of way, you can install `pysnap` so that `pysnap` will not try to install `cryptography`

Comment: I'm using Mac OS. I tried 'pip install cryptography' but it raises 'Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cryptography (from versions: )
  No matching distribution found for cryptography'